# Can I integrate Cmder in VS Code on a Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal-emulator, cmder

Is there a way where I can use Cmder in VS code on Mac? And if so, then how do I integrate it?

If not, do you know any good alternatives?

I've thought about using Hyper as an alternative, but I cannot get it to look the way I want it to, and it doesn't seem to have the same "intelligence". For instance, if I want to go back into the prev. directory, I have to type `cd ..`, whereas in Cmder I can type `cd..` or `cd ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use cmder in VS Code on a Mac.
I have tried to look for some alternatives, but ended up using Hyper.io
Hopefully there will come an alternative with the "Intellisence" feature Cmder has which I really like.

Answer (score 0):

You can set powershell link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-6)

```
brew cask install powershell
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? Does this mean that you can't add Cmder to VS Code on a Mac? Or is this just your suggestion of an alternative?

Comment: yes .Cmder is a component from native cmd windows, alternativate to most like that you need is posible once you install powershell [windows subsystem for linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), i'm working with c# and linux , but really not test in OS.